# FOREACH sql table entry get result from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach, vbulletin

I'm working with vBulletin forums and I'm trying to get results from one table if it exists in another table.

This is the creation of the table the data is from

```
$db->query("ALTER TABLE " . TABLE_PREFIX . "drc_settings ADD thread_ids varchar(50) NOT NULL default '0'");
```

I have created an input field meant for comma separated numbers (thread ID's). That submits to this column, so a result in this column would look like:

```
1,46,23
```

Another column in this table is threadid, this is the thread the post was submitted from.

So this is what we have in the drc_settings table

```
threadid  thread_ids
   5       1,46,23
```

Now another table that exists is thread, in the thread table we have:

```
threadid  title
   46     Some Title
```

What I need to know is, how do I get the title from thread if thread_ids or drc_settings match threadid of thread?

This is where I'm at with it, but I'm a little out of my element on this one.

```
$res = $post['thread_ids'];
$res = explode (',', $res);
$post['drcid'] = '<ul>';

foreach ( $res as $ret ) {
$db->query("
  SELECT
  thread.threadid, drc.threadid AS threadid,
  thread.threadid, thread.title AS threadtitle
  FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread AS thread
  LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "drc_settings AS drc ON (drc.threadid=thread.threadid)
  WHERE thread.threadid VAR (" . $ret . ")
");  
$post['drcid'] .= '<li><a href="showthread.php?t=' . $ret . '">'.   $thread[threadtitle] .'</a></li>';
}
$post['drcid'] .= '</ul>';
```

If I remove the query from the foreach, I am able to get $res to return 1 46 23
which is stumping me why the query isn't working properly.

The end result will be a list of links to each thread specified in the input, I.E:

- Some Title
- Another thread
- Thread Title

This is the error returned with the current setup I have

```
Database error in vBulletin 3.8.9:

Invalid SQL:

                SELECT
        thread.threadid, drc.threadid AS threadid,
                    thread.threadid, thread.title AS threadtitle
                FROM thread AS thread
                LEFT JOIN drc_settings AS drc ON (drc.threadid=thread.threadid)
                WHERE thread.threadid VAR (1);

MySQL Error   : You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Comment: Storing delimited lists of key is a terrible way of desiging a database

Comment: I didn't design this database, its vBulletin forum software.  I'm just creating a plugin for it.  But anything you have to suggest on improving it, I'm listening =)

Comment: This non-1NF database structure is vbulletin's fault.  yourmom didn't create the structure, only using what others have produced.  Wasn't this question asked yesterday?  and FIND_IN_SET() was suggested?

Comment: Yup, with no luck, and a few comments pretty much saying "DON'T DO THAT" with little reasoning why not to. I re-asked because of the lack of responses, and I changed up the code a little since.  The other thread has been deleted.

Comment: Query MUST be failing to return all the columns, as you are asking to generate 3 columns in the resultset with the name of `threadid` so use `AS` to alias and give 2 of them other names

Comment: Is there a query error on VAR? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: yes one moment will post the error in the OP, should have already done that lol

Comment: Yea Mom, remember we are not looking over your shoulder, we can only help if you give us all the information

Comment: =P I added it, that was totally my bad

Comment: Can you run this in your phpmyadmin?  What is happening with that VAR() portion?  I can't find any explanation on that.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for that comment, I thought I was the only one that was confused by that

Comment: MYSQL errors normally come with a bit more info than that. Normally say something like `near ' and some of your query` which should give us a bit more of a clue

Comment: Back to the FIND_IN_SET (that you were copping shame about yesterday)  can you JOIN ON FIND_IN_SET(thread.threadid,drc.threadids) ?

Comment: Your general query error is talking about `modsys_settings` where did that one come from?    ...you just manually edited it out of your post?  Are you giving us the real info here?

Comment: honestly I have no clue, I know what I'm trying to achieve just not how to get there.  SQL is a new ball game to me, I've only ever created tables and added to them before this.  I found that query in another plugin and thought I could adapt it to function how I needed.  The thread title is in the thread table and my plugin data is in the drc_settings table, and just want to get the thread title out of thread table, IF that threadid matches any of the threadid's in the drc_settings table.

Comment: your WHERE condition doesn't have an = sign.

Comment: yeah i had to ctrl - z in the plugin file and went back too far, I renamed it though, everything is correct.

Comment: do you still want me to attempt to run this in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136200/discussion-between-your-mom-and-mickmackusa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $ret (the parent threadid)...

```
$query="SELECT B.threadid,B.title 
    FROM drc.settings A 
    LEFT JOIN thread B 
    ON FIND_IN_SET(B.threadid,A.threadids) 
    WHERE A.threadid={$ret};"
```

Then loop through the resultset as needed to build the $post array.